# Proving on $ 1-|x| \le \sqrt[n]{1+x} \le 1+|x| $

Tags: inequality

> Prove that
> $$ 1-|x| \le \sqrt [n] {1+x} \le 1+|x| $$
> for $|x| < 1 $.

I can raise both sides to the nth power and get ${(1-|x|)}^n \le 1+x$. How can I prove this?
By using $ 1 - |x| < 1$ so ${(1- |x|)}^n \le 1 - |x|?$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly, use the following properties: $a^n\leq a$ when $0\leq a\leq 1$ and $a^n\geq a$ when $a\geq1$. Then  for $|x|<1$, we have that
$$(1-|x|)^n\leq 1-|x| \le 1+x \le 1+|x|\leq (1+|x|)^n.$$